# AWS Lex Response Message based on the slot Value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, aws-lex

Is there a way to have response messages within an intent, based on the value selected in a slot?

I.e. If Slot1 = "Value 1" then Message1 , If slot1 = "value2" Then Message2?